# Output lines of a file, specified by line number, with only bash (no sed, grep, or awk)

Tags: bash, shell

*Without* using tools such as `sed`, `grep`, or `awk`, only standard shell, I need to retrieve line numbers of lines containing a pattern then, then for each line number retrieved, output lines:

```
[(line_retrieved) + 1 - (line_retrieved % 6)] to [line_retrieved + 6]
```

while skipping duplicate blocks of lines.

I was able to output lines of a file, specified by line number with `sed "${START_LINE}, ${END_LINE}" file`. I haven't found how to  retrieve line numbers of lines containing a pattern yet.

Comment: ...why do you have these restrictions? These are ...uncommon enough to warrant explanation.

Comment: Please specify what kind of pattern, and how many lines a set of duplicate blocks might be.  Also show some sample input and the desired output.  Apart from the duplicate blocks stuff, it sounds as though the goal is to simulate `grep -C 6 pattern` in `bash`.  If so, the `% 6` should be `- 6`.

Comment: Right now, this smells like "please do my homework for me", vs a question about a specific problem encountered while writing your own code. **Showing your work** is a good place to start in terms of avoiding that impression.

Comment: BTW, if you're still trying to figure out how to get started (in terms of creating some work you can show), see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) (*How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*)

Comment: To be clear, questions that you came across while trying to do homework can be perfectly valid here -- see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) for guidance on how to ask one that's well-received. Key is that it should be a question about a *specific* problem with an *existing* implementation, posed after making a good-faith effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Assuming your pattern is "giga.*" (for example if you want to catch "gigaaks") and the file is /tmp/1.txt then you'd do something like:

you would do:

```
 pattern="giga.*"; linenum=1; while read line; do for word in `echo $line`; do if [[ "$word" =~ "$string_to_search" ]]; then echo $linenum:$line; fi; done; ((linenum++)); done < /tmp/1.txt | sort -u
```

**Overview:**
1) I set my pattern in `pattern` variable. Value can be exact string or an actual pattern.

2) You read the file line by line in outer loop and read that whole line into a variable $line.

3) Then you read the whole line to read all the words in that line, into a variable $word.

4) Then you use IF statement with `=~` SHELL level direct regex match (using =~ operator)

5) If 4th statement is true, then you echo the $linenum (containing the line#) and the whole $line line.

6) You increment $linenum per every outer loop run (i.e. for each line).

7) `sort -u` will be used to print the line only ONCE if pattern/string occurs more than one time in a line's word(s).

It'll spit all the patterns with the full line, prefixed with the LINE# of each line from the file.

NOTE: if you want to do `grep -i` (ignore case), then you may try the actual grep -i or similar capability.

Comment: No, this has some common problems. Try http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnosing a good number of them.

Comment: @tripleee worked fine at my end. Can you share what problems?

Comment: You clearly tested with (too) unchallenging test data. Again, try http://shellcheck.net/ for detailed diagnostics.